# Oracle - how to see how many blocks have been used in a table

Tags: oracle

I have very limited experience when using Oracle, and am after a rather simple query I imagine. I have a table which contains 1 million rows, Im trying to proof that compressing the data uses less space, however im not sure how to do this, based on this table creation below could someone please show me what i need to write to see the blocks used before/after?

```
CREATE TABLE OrderTableCompressed(OrderID, StaffID, CustomerID, TotalOrderValue)
as (select level, ceil(dbms_random.value(0, 1000)), 
                  ceil(dbms_random.value(0,10000)), 
                  round(dbms_random.value(0,10000),2) 
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 1000000);

ALTER TABLE OrderTableCompressed ADD CONSTRAINT OrderID_PKC PRIMARY KEY (OrderID);

--QUERY HERE THAT SHOWS BLOCKS USED/TIME TAKEN
SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM OrderTableCompressed;

ALTER TABLE OrderTableCompressed COMPRESS;

--QUERY HERE THAT SHOWS BLOCKS USED/TIME TAKEN WHEN COMPRESSED
SELECT COUNT(ORDERID) FROM OrderTableCompressed;
```

I know how the compression works etc... its just applying the code to proove my theory. thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--QUERY HERE THAT SHOWS BLOCKS USED
SELECT blocks, bytes/1024/1024 as MB 
FROM user_segments 
where segment_name = 'ORDERTABLECOMPRESSED';
```

Now compress the table: (Note the `move`. Without it you just change the attribute of the table and subsequent direct path inserts will create compressed blocks)

```
ALTER TABLE OrderTableCompressed MOVE COMPRESS;
```

Verify blocks:

```
--QUERY HERE THAT SHOWS BLOCKS USED TAKEN WHEN COMPRESSED
SELECT blocks, bytes/1024/1024 as MB 
FROM user_segments 
where segment_name = 'ORDERTABLECOMPRESSED';
```

Comment: thankyou, it turns out I am doing something right in using AutoTrace, yet I dont have the permissions to show it haha!! thankyou once again